# Add Recent Pages Link To Website HTML

Tags: php, html, cookies, hyperlink

I am starting a new blog/community tutorial website (no I am *not* using WordPress, I'm doing the PHP myself).

**I was wondering if there was an easy way with cookies/PHP to add a box that shows recently viewed pages.**

If the user looks up some tutorial pages, I want the links to display on the side of the page.

(Kind of like stackoverflow's "Similar Questions" box on the right).

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

**Side Note:** Should I implement Google+ for people to log in? If so, how (I assume I would use server-flow)? If not, should I make my own?

Comment: Do users have to login, or do you need this to support anonymous users?

Comment: For now, if users are going to submit stuff they need to have an account/login and not be anonymous.

Comment: But isn't the "recently viewed" list going to be for users who view, not only submitters? What I'm getting at is if they login, you can store the recent list in your database. If not, you'll probably have to use cookies.

Comment: I see... yes I would rather use cookies so ALL people can view recent pages. How can I do this?